# How to get access to the XMLHttpRequest errors added via addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying but not finding a way.

[image]

Comment: Why use `xhr.addEventListener`? Just use `xhr.onerror = e=>{ console.log(e.message); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange thing to want to do, but if you had to, you could monkeypatch `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener`:

```js
const errorHandlers = [];
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener = function(...args) {
  if (args[0] === 'error') {
    errorHandlers.push(args[1]);
  }
  return EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this, args);
};

const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.addEventListener('error', () => console.log('handle error'));

console.log(errorHandlers);
```

Make sure to patch `addEventListener` *before* the code that calls `addEventListener` runs.